# change scale with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to change the scale of a graph rendered by d3.js.

This is an excerpt of what I came up with (whole code on Plunker, see below):

```
var toggleZoom = function() {
  switch(state) {
  case 'zoomed_in':
    state = 'zoomed_out';
    scaleX = d3.scale.linear().rangeRound([0, width]).domain([min_out, max_out]);
    break;
  case 'zoomed_out':
    state = 'zoomed_in';
    scaleX = d3.scale.linear().rangeRound([0, width]).domain([min_in, max_in]);
    break;  
  }
  update(); // uses scaleX to render the graph
}
```

While this renders the graph initialy in the expected way, it refuses to make any changes to the graph on subsequent calls of the function above.

I guess this is not the d3.js' style of doing it. What would be a more promising approach?

I also looked into d3's zoom behavior, but that doesn't seem a good fit in this case, since this is really only about switch between to scales on only one axis.

Here is the Plunker to play around with: http://plnkr.co/edit/3qoQoSerohiC9xFAuXyI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually redrawing the graph. You're handling only the enter selection, which will be empty on subsequent calls as the `rect` elements already exist. To fix, handle the update selection as well:

```
var sel = svg.selectAll('rect').data(data);
sel
.enter().append('rect');
sel
.attr('x', function(d) { return scaleX(d.p) })
.attr('width', function(d) { return scaleX(d.p+d.l)-scaleX(d.p) } )
.attr('height', height)
.attr('fill', function(d) { return d.c });
```

Complete demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lbNPfCW4zwvmqgn4WsHA?p=preview).